# Create Executable progeam of addition in C on linux

Tags: c, linux

I am new to Linux. Sorry I am asking very basic question. On windows I have Main.cpp file having code for addition of two number. In Visual studio gives me .exe. But how to do it on Linux. On my Linux machine have gcc compiler no IDE.
What I write in Make file and how to run.

Main.cpp has code like

```
#include <stido.h>
#include <conio.h>
// Static library file included
//#include "Add.h"
int main()
{
    int a,b,c;

    a = 10;
    b = 20;

    c= a+b;
    //Add function in static lib (.a in case of linux)
    //c= Add(a,b);
    printf("Addition is :%d",c);


    return 0;
}
```

After that I want use Add function which is in Addition. How to use with above program removing commented in code?

Comment: You certainly _can_ use manually written Makefiles for compilation and linkage. However it is simply not true that there are no development GUIs available under Linux.

Comment: I know there is no default extension in Linux. I want to run above example by creating make file.

Comment: @arkascha : GUI are available but not I want to do without using it. So i can switch to any Linux flavor without IDE.

Comment: <conio.h> is a C header file used in MS-DOS. The <curses.h> will give you almost all the functionalities that was provided in <conio.h>

Answer (score 2):

For c++ code, the command is usually something like:

```
g++ Main.cpp -o FileNameToWriteTo
```

Alternatively, if you just run

```
g++ Main.cpp
```

it will output to a default file called a.out.

Either way, you can then run whichever file you created by doing:

```
./FileNameToWriteTo.out
```

See this for more details: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~beechung/ref/gcc-intro.html

Comment: Thanks :) .g++ hello.C -o hello \n This command compiles hello.C into an executable program named "hello" that you run by typing 'hello' at the command line. It does nothing more than print the word "hello" on the screen. \n Now I want to link .a file to hello and call function from .a file like add as mentioned above in question.